# select where column with a %

Tags: sql-server, select, like

How can I select all records with a `%` in? I think this code doesn't work.

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%%%'
```

- first and last `%` for zero, one or more chars
- second `%` for the percent skinn

Can anyone suggest me how it can work? I use MS-SQL server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For special characters (`%` and `_`), you need to escape them:

```
WHERE column LIKE '%[%]%';
```

or

```
WHERE column LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\';
```

This is covered in [the documentation for LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), in the sections "Using Wildcard Characters as Literals" and "Pattern Matching with the ESCAPE Clause." Your first stop should always be the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `ESCAPE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE '%\%%' escape '\';
```

You can use any character for escaping the `%` sign:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE '%~%%' escape '~';
```